# Can we use hearty as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

In the movie '300', the protagonist King Leonidas has a famous dialogue.

> Spartans! Ready your breakfast and eat hearty, for tonight, we dine in
>   hell!

Here, I wanted to know if the usage of hearty as an adverb is right.

Is not heartily the right adverb?

Comment: You're right but remember - This! Is! Sparta! and pesky English grammar rules need not apply.

Comment: This may be a flat adverb, but it may also be an adjective (“eat hearty [food]”).

Comment: I never realized how silly this line is.  "Eat hearty, for tonight we dine in Hell - and the food there is terrible...and such small portions"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet interesting thought!

Comment: @KillingTime haha very well

Comment: @Juhasz yeah, in fact it should be better with everything fried / roasted. 
Someone put rock salt in my coffin.

Answer (score 2):

In informal speech it is quite common to find certain adjectives used as adverbs - eat hearty, rest easy, come quick, want something bad, etc.

Poem:
[Adverbs Used Real Awful](https://colonialist.wordpress.com/2015/07/21/adverbs-used-real-awful/)

Oxford Etymologist: [Do It Real Quick, Or The Death Of The Adverb](https://blog.oup.com/2007/08/adverb/)

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that the usage somehow makes it more pleasing to the ears.